# Selenium Webdriver 'query is not selectable' error

Tags: c#, button, click, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2013

I am using selenium webdriver to navigate through pages in my web application. What should really be a simple 'click this button' instruction fails, and I can't seem to figure out why.

I am using the code:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(input[value='View results'])).Click();
```

and while this method has worked in other similar situations it fails to find the button for this situation. The button is just that, a button on a web page. Selenium webdriver can find it, but when it clicks on it says it is 'not a selectable' query. I can't figure out why, if done manually the button takes the user to the next page. Selenium webdriver is just having an issue with it.

I can't seem to figure out why??

```
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select position</legend>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="PositionId">Position</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <select id="PositionId" name="PositionId">
    <option value="49">5396c05f-7496-4ce1-8d98-841a1df1b9b6</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="View results">
    </form>
```

Comment: Quotes are missing in the following `By.CssSelector("input[value='View results']")`,is this a typo?

Comment: @Amith, good spot, though Visual Studio would treat that as C# code and not a string literal (because of the missing quotes), and wouldn't compile - I would assume anyway.

Answer (score -1):

i think there is an "@" missing in your code.

Try this:

```
By.CssSelector("input[@value='View results']"
```

Comment: That would be right for the XPath selector, not the CSS one.